# Using nvarchar(max) in Azure stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure, adodb, nvarchar

We are testing moving from a local MSSQL db to Azure.

We have an old ASP classic site which we need to maintain that creates an ADODB command to store email messages using a MSSQL stored procedure. The Body column is of type nvarchar(max).

The ADODB code is as follows:

```
set azurecon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set azurecmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
azurecon.Open   sconn
azurecmd.ActiveConnection = azurecon
azurecmd.CommandType = 4
azurecmd.CommandText = "sp_add_mail"
azurecmd.Parameters.refresh
azurecmd.Parameters("@FromAddress")= fromemail
azurecmd.Parameters("@ToAddress")= toemail
azurecmd.Parameters("@Subject")= subject
azurecmd.Parameters("@Body")= body
azurecmd.Execute
```

And the stored procedure is:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_add_mail] ( @FromAddress nvarchar(32), 
                                       @ToAddress nvarchar(48),
                                       @Subject nvarchar(160),
                                       @Body nvarchar(max))
AS
    INSERT INTO tbl_Mail(FromAddress, ToAddress, Subject, Body)
    VALUES ( @FromAddress, @ToAddress, @Subject, @Body )
```

We copied the table and the stored procedure to Azure, but when running the code we receive the following error: Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

However if we change the stored procedure from @Body nvarchar(max) to a fixed value for example @Body nvarchar(4000) everything works.

Is there a different requirement when sending nvarchar(max) parameters to Azure?

Comment: I'm not sure it will solve the problem., but Instead of `azurecmd.Parameters("@Body")= body` try `azurecmd.CreateParameter ("@Body", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, -1, body)` The -1 represents size for `max` columns.

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Also, as an FYI, the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: I vaguely remember `Parameters.refresh` calls some stored procedure behind the scenes `sp_procedure_params_rowset`. If you use extended events to see the commands being run does it call the same proc in both cases? And does that proc return the same results in both cases?

Comment: @Zohar - your suggestion generates a different error:

Error Source: azurecmd.CreateParameter ("@Body", DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, -1, body)
Error Description: Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub

Comment: Remove the parentheses and this error goes away. However @MartinSmith's comment have caused me to go read up on `Parameters.refresh` and from what I understand my suggestion would cause a different error since `Parameters.Refresh` already adds the parameters - so instead of calling `CreateParameters` instead try to just sepcify the size of the `@Body` parameter:
`azurecmd.Parameters("@Body").Size = -1` and keep the `azurecmd.Parameters("@Body")= body` row (though to be honest, I dislike the concept of "default properties" and would rather explicitly mention the property name instead.

Comment: Call `CreateParameter` with the correct size `azurecmd.Parameters.CreateParameter("@Body", adVarWChar, Size:= -1, Value:= body)`

Comment: This works. Thanks

azurecmd.Parameters("@Body").Size = -1

Comment: In that case, please consider posting an answer to your own question (and accept it when possible) so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following works:

```
azurecmd.Parameters("@Body").Size = -1 
azurecmd.Parameters("@Body")= body
```